# Remove duplicates in array

Tags: php

Here is the code for storing unique values to a variable.

```
$filtermodel = array_unique($list2);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => 15592
[1] => 182
[4] => 14208
[7] => 183
[11] => 184,185,186
[15] => 174
[16] => 177
[23] => 184,186
[24] => 184,185,186,187
[29] => 179
[38] => 188
[41] => 174,176,184,185,186,187
 )
```

Above `array key[11] contains 184,185,186` and `key[23][24]` contains same as `key[11]`. How to remove those duplicates in array? Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are not duplicates. Those elements contain _strings_, not elements devided by commas.

Comment: Instead of removing try to prevent at the time of insertion

Comment: @arkascha Ok. Then how can I remove those exists elements in array. Please help me

Comment: What is the expected output? Which one should be removed?

Comment: `print_r(array_unique(explode(',',implode(',',$yourArray))));` :-)

Comment: @Niklesh those values are not inserting. It's getting directly from database.

Comment: Sorry, but it appears that you did not (bother to) understand my comment. Those are not separate elements. You have an array holding 12 strings. There are no duplicates in that array.

Comment: Please propose the result you want to receive.

Comment: @Jakub Matczak. Expected output is remove the values if already existed in array

Comment: @arkascha. Expected result is below hereArray
(
[0] => 15592
[1] => 182
[4] => 14208
[7] => 183
[11] => 184,185,186
[15] => 174
[16] => 177
[24] => 187
[29] => 179
[38] => 188
[41] => 176
 )

Comment: Please never add additional information in comments. Add it to the question. There is an `edit` link below it. _Use it!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with a foreach over each element in array and explode by comma `,` then do a unique on the resulted list of strings

Here is a [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c2b25f6e5658d0860e6b4864f2f5c08bd973b10)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Pleavă Sorin thank you very much its working fine, I am really happy. I was stuck on 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that the '182,186' for example is an array of integers and got right what you are trying to achieve the below works :

If not then please consider pointing out better what are you trying to achieve

```
$mArray = array(
    15592,
    182,
    14208,
    183,
    array(184,185,186),
    174,
    177,
    array(184,186),
    array(184,185,186,187),
    179,
    188,
    array(174,176,184,185,186,187),
);


$mFinalArray = [];

foreach($mArray as $currentObject)
    if(!is_array($currentObject) && !in_array($currentObject, $mFinalArray))
       $mFinalArray[] = $currentObject;
    else if(is_array($currentObject))
        foreach($currentObject as $currentObjectInside)
            if(!in_array($currentObjectInside, $mFinalArray))
                $mFinalArray[] = $currentObjectInside;

sort($mFinalArray);

print_r($mFinalArray);
```

> Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 174
    [1] => 176
    [2] => 177
    [3] => 179
    [4] => 182
    [5] => 183
    [6] => 184
    [7] => 185
    [8] => 186
    [9] => 187
    [10] => 188
    [11] => 14208
    [12] => 15592
)
```

Comment: That code is extremely hard to read and error prone. There are reasons for coding standards...

Comment: Can't really understand what you mean by "There are reasons for coding standards" but please consider helping me out and explaining(with just a link if available) to understand the bad thing you can see in my coding  - would really appreciate it

Comment: Coding standards help all of us to understand and work with code _others_ wrote. If every programmer uses his/her own dialect this only adds complexity. Instead programmers agree on coding standards, also called coding style or coding conventions. For a start you should place curly braces around every block of code, so here to your conditionals and loops. Yes, they are optional from a syntactic point of view, but nevertheless leaving them out is considered bad style.

Comment: I will keep it in mind!! Thanks for pointing out something that i should pay attention to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) with passing by reference, using the third parameter (userdata) as dictionary for used values:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$item, $_, &$dict) {
    $values = explode(',', $item);

    $item = implode(',', array_filter($values, function ($value) use (&$dict) {
        // If value already in the dictionary, just skip it.
        if (isset($dict[$value])) {
            return false;
        }

        // Add value to the dictionary and not filter it out.
        return $dict[$value] = true;
    }));
}, []);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abd569aac8d7dc2b36ed06a5fb99aeafe1448aa2).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a foreach loop and for each row contains ',' symbol try using explode.

You can also create an array just for holding the existing values for later check if they exist.

Simple example-

```
$unique_values = [];

$all_values = array (
  [0] => 15592
  [1] => 182
  [4] => 14208
  [7] => 183
  [11] => 184,185,186
  [15] => 174
  [16] => 177
  [23] => 184,186
  [24] => 184,185,186,187
  [29] => 179
  [38] => 188
  [41] => 174,176,184,185,186,187
);

foreach( $all_values as $av ) {
  if( strpos( $av, ',' ) !== false ) {
    $av = explode( ',', $av );

    foreach( $av as $a ) {
      array_push( $unique_values, $a );
      array_unique( $unique_values );

      $result = !empty( array_intersect( $unique_values, $a ) );
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't test this code but i made it for explaining the logic.